# Custom Enfold theme tab layout not compatible with WPML

Tags: theme-development, themes, plugin-wpml

I'm trying to create a new page with the Avia Layout Architect but there are some problems. I used the health check plugin to disable all plugins and tested if the tab works with my custom theme, which it does. However, as soon as I activate WPML, the tabs are broken. How they are broken is visible from the image attached.
I have to state that I'm not sure if the tabs ever worked with WPML. I got the responsibility for the website but didn't design it and don't have too much knowledge about WordPress. Could you guide me towards a solution so that I can use the tabs with WPML? How would I go towards solving this? [image]

Comment: I'd check your browser's debug tools console to see if there are any errors there, to try and work out what's going wrong? But this might be a question for WPML or Avia once you know what the actual problem is.

Comment: The problem is that neither WPML nor Avia offer support for customized themes. The theme was customized by a contractor a few years ago and I know nothing about it and only little about WordPress. I'll try and check the console though, thanks